# Which version of WiredTiger is being used by MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

Is it possible to find out which version of WiredTiger I am using with MongoDB?
I tried using:-

```
db.serverStatus().wiredTiger
```

but I can't find any version info in there.

I installed MongoDB (v3.0.4) out of the box, so I'm trying to figure out what version of WiredTiger it ships with, and whether or not I can use a newer version of WiredTiger instead.

Comment: FYI, there was also discussion on the mongodb-dev list about upgrading WiredTiger independently of the version shipped with MongoDB: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-dev/31FQSo4KVCI. The short summary from the WiredTiger team is "the only version of WiredTiger guaranteed to be compatible with any particular release of MongoDB is the version of WiredTiger that's included in the MongoDB release; you should not upgrade WiredTiger separately."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source for 3.0.4 suggests that you are using WiredTiger 2.5.3:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/r3.0.4/src/third_party/wiredtiger

> WiredTiger 2.5.3: (March 26, 2015)
>
> This is version 2.5.3 of WiredTiger.

You can, of course, recompile and attempt to use another version, but you may find it easier to take a look at a dev branch instead and try out newer versions that way, for example:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/r3.1.6/src/third_party/wiredtiger

MongoDB 3.1.6 seems to be using WiredTiger 2.6.2:

> WiredTiger 2.6.2: (June  4, 2015)
>
> This is version 2.6.2 of WiredTiger.